# сравнить 2 списка <string> на поиск элементов Contains

Tags: c#, linq

необходимо сравнить 2 списка List. Если содержится в списке слово с другим словом, то ничего не делаем, иначе пишем в стрингбилдер. Я знаю что для сравнения с одним элементом используется Contains  и у меня выходит рабочая версия:

```
      foreach (var item in items)
    {
       if (item.Key.ToLower().Contains("connection"))
                continue;
        sb.AppendLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value}");
    }
```

Но как я могу сделать Contains не с одним словом, а с другим списком стрингов? Т.Е у меня будет лист
`List<string> list = new List<string>() {"connection","cinnection"}` и вот как мне в цикле foreach сравнивать каждый элемент со всеми элементами в списке list?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `Except`/`Intersect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list1 = new List<string>()
{
    "word1", "Word2", "word3"
};
var list2 = new List<string>()
{
    "word4", "word5", "word2"
};
var result = list1.Select(x => x.ToLower()).Intersect(list2.Select(x => x.ToLower())).ToList(); //"word2"
```

[Полезная статья по коллекциям](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.4.php)

UPD (сокращённый вариант aepot):

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList(); //"word2"
```

Comment: спасибо, почти то что надо, но есть проблемка. Contains при поиске "connection" подтянет все связанные записи (connectionString. connectionPower, superConnection и тп), а Interest добавляет именно одинаковые записи. есть ли возможность искать записи, с Contains?

Comment: @Петян Что значит "подтянет все связанные записи"? Дополните вопрос примерами данных, которые обрабатываются и вашим ожидаемым результатом

Comment: а, все так, работает. Спасибо

Comment: @Петян вот покороче `var result = list1.Intersect(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();`